# How to remove shifting effect(zoom effect) for icons in roughike ANDROID?

Tags: android

How would you disable the zoom effect when an icon is clicked on the bottom bar?
I've tried using `useFixedMode()` but the function is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong library.
You can use this library in gradle:

```
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
```

and then try using

```
bottombar.useFixedMode();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the customised bottom navigation bar instead of rough hike.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvBottomNavigationBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_item_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_iv_0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_iv_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_iv_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="6dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```